# How can I make bootstrap-table column-sort icons more visible?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I'm using [bootstrap-table](https://bootstrap-table.com) to create a table with Bootstrap 4, with sorting enabled for columns. It works fantastically well, except for one small detail: the little arrows in the column headings are almost invisible. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How can I make the up/down icons larger, darker, or otherwise more visible?

Answer (score 1):

The colors for Bootstrap-table’s default arrow images don’t provide much color contrast, especially with the light gray background color you’re using for your table (compared to the white background Bootstrap-table uses in their examples), and the arrows are hard-coded as base64 images, so not easy to change.

If you want arrows with better color contrast in line with the WCAG 2 AA guidelines, you’ll need to override the base64 images that Bootstrap Table has in their CSS. You can add custom CSS after Bootstrap Table’s CSS file to override their styles with styles that use SVG images, something like:

```
th {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .both {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.56'%3E%3Cpolygon points='50,10 70,45 30,45'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='30,55 70,55 50,90' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-size: 1.1875rem, 1.1875rem;
}

.bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .asc {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.69'%3E%3Cpolygon points='50,10 70,45 30,45'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-size: 1.1875rem, 1.1875rem;
}

.bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .desc {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.69'%3E%3Cpolygon points='30,55 70,55 50,90' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-size: 1.1875rem, 1.1875rem;
} /* IE10 & 11 want URL encoded open and close characters */
```

Bootstrap Table’s double arrow image uses a light gray color, #DCDCDC. Against a white background, the gray has only a 1.4 to 1 contrast ratio. Against your gray header background, the ratio is only 1.2 to 1. The WCAG guidelines recommend a 4.5 to 1 contrast ratio for normal text. The ascending / descending arrows use a slate blue color, #7A80DD.  Against a white background the slate blue has a 3.5 to 1 contrast ratio, which is still below the recommended 4.5 to 1 ratio. Against your gray header background, the ratio is 3.0 to 1.

I’ve setup the SVG images to use a black (#000000) fill and I vary the opacity to get sufficient contrast (the way Google recommends in their [Material Design specification](https://material.io/design/color/text-legibility.html#text-backgrounds)).

Against a white background, for the double arrow, an opacity of 54% would give a 4.6 contrast ratio and, for the single arrows, an opacity of 65% would give a 7.0 contrast ratio. Both values are enough for most people to be able to see the indicators.

Against a light gray background (e.g. #e0e0e0, which is the gray used for Material Design headers), opacities of 56% and 69% would give contrast ratios of 4.6 and 7.3, which is what I configured the demo code to use.

The background SVG images use URL encoding for the less-than '< and greater-than '>' symbols in the string to work with IE 10 & 11 (I tested the styles on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, and it works on those three browsers).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<style>
    th {
        background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }
    .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .both {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.56'%3E%3Cpolygon points='50,10 70,45 30,45'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='30,55 70,55 50,90' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        background-size: 19px, 19px;
    }

    .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .asc {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.69'%3E%3Cpolygon points='50,10 70,45 30,45'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        background-size: 19px, 19px;
    }

    .bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .desc {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23000000' opacity='0.69'%3E%3Cpolygon points='30,55 70,55 50,90' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        background-size: 19px, 19px;
    } /* IE10 & 11 want URL encoded open and close characters */
</style>

<table data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-sortable="true" data-field="id">Item ID</th>
        <th data-sortable="true" data-field="name">Item Name</th>
        <th data-sortable="true" data-field="price">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>$1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>$2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

While there isn't a significant amount of contrast between the double arrow and the asc and decs arrows, they will all be visible to more users than Bootstrap Table's standard images, and the opacities can be increased, if desired.